# Python String Slicing: What is the semantic logic of the expression s[-1:-len(s)-1:-1] with arbitrary string s?

Tags: python, string, slice

With arbitrary string s, `s[::-1]` inverts the string and is equivalent to `s[-1:-len(s)-1:-1]`.

For example: with `s = "abc"` , `s[::-1]` and `s[-1:-len(s)-1:-1]` produce `"cba"`.

I am wondering if anyone can explain the stop position of the latter expression  `-len(s)-1`. I found nothing in the Python docs which elaborate on string slicing stop position syntax besides provided integer values and colons as default `s[len(s)]`.

Comment: I guess someone just did not know that the middle part of the slice can be left empty to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Negative indices are essentially operating on principles of modular arithmetic.

They wrap around to the end of the list. So `s[-1]` is the last character in the string, `s[-2]` is the second-to-last character in the string, ... all the way to `s[-len(s)]` is therefore the first character in the string.

Because we want to include the first character and slices don't include the "upper" bound, we use `-len(s)-1` as the stopping point for the reversal. That is, the slice starts at `-1` and increments by a further `-1` each time, with the last index it includes being `-len(s)` which corresponds to the first character of the string.